# Does non-EU citizen with UK residence permit need health insurance

Tags: schengen, insurance

Does a non-EU citizen living in UK as spouse of UK national with permanent residence permit need health insurance for a short stay Schengen visa?

Comment: What sort of residence permit? Limited stay or indefinite leave to remain? Is the spouse entitled to contributory benefits, and have they paid National Insurance before now?

Comment: FWIW last time me and my (Non-EU) wife travelled to Germany, we took out travel insurance, even though (I believe) we'd both be covered under the EHIC as she's in work and pays National Insurance. Though she has a 90-day visa waiver for Schengen area so we didn't need to go through the full process.

Comment: Also be aware that any answer given here might change after Brexit.

Comment: @MichaelDodd "permanent residence permit" implies ILR.